# Migrations run out of gas

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am using Ganache. I have unboxed pet shop. Then inside the contracts folder, I made a file `Election.sol` which has the code,

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;  

contract Election{
    string public candidate;
    constructor() public{
        candidate = "candidate 1"; //state var

    }   
}
```

Then inside migrations folder, I made `2_deploy_contract.js` which has the code

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election );
};
```

When I do truffle migrate using command `-truffle migrate`, I get this error.

```
Compiling your contracts...
Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

Migrations dry-run (simulation)
Network name: 'development-fork' Network id: 1 Block gas limit: 0x1388

1_initial_migration.js
Deploying 'Migrations'

Error: Error: Error: * Deployment Failed *

"Migrations" ran out of gas (using Truffle's estimate.) * Block limit: 0x50e7c * Gas sent: undefined * Try: + Setting a higher gas estimate multiplier for this contract + Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js' + Making your contract smaller + Making your contract constructor more efficient + Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a private network or test client (like ganache).

at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I have seen some solutions posted to a problem similar to this but it could not solve mine.

Comment: Question looks good, I will check and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, @Div!! Please let me know. I am stuck on this for a long time and I am not being able to proceed.

Comment: When I run "ganache-cli", it says - command not found.  
When I do "npm install -g ganache-cli"
I get this error-
/home/neha/.npm-global/bin/ganache-cli -> /home/neha/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js
/home/neha/.npm-global/lib
`-- ganache-cli@6.4.4

Comment: You can try to set gas manually like deployer.deploy(Election,{gas: 155000})